# Insufficient permissions issue while deploying a firebase function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I deployed a firebase function with the command `firebase deploy --only "functions:onWikiWrite"`.

I got this error: `Error: Functions did not deploy properly.`. The firebase functions logs say

> "status":{"code":7,"message":"Insufficient permissions to (re)configure a trigger (permission denied for bucket myBucket). Please, give owner permissions to the editor role of the bucket and try again.

Typescript Code

```js
import * as functions from "firebase-functions";
import * as admin from "firebase-admin";

import serviceAccount from "/Users/300041370/Downloads/serviceKey.json";

admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
});

const buckObj = functions.storage.bucket("myBucket").object();
export const onWikiWrite = buckObj.onFinalize(async (object) => {
  const filePath = object.name ?? "test.json";
  const bucket = admin.storage().bucket("myBucket");

  bucket.file(filePath).download().then((data) => {
    const contents = data[0];
  data = {"key": "value"};
const doc = admin.firestore().collection("myCollection").doc();
doc.set(data);
  });
});
```

Service Account Roles of the service account of this function 
[image: Service Account Roles]

Comment: Do you really have the double quotes in `firebase deploy --only "functions:onWikiWrite"` CLI command?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec yes

Comment: What happens if you do `firebase deploy --only functions:onWikiWrite`?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec Same thing happens.